# Can I use the 'cp' command with the -b option, but have it fail if the backup file already exists?

Tags: backup, file-copy

I'd like to use `cp -b` to copy a file to a destination, possibly creating a backup file of the destination path if it already exists. But, if the *backup file* already exists, I'd like to have `cp` fail with an error.

I know I can use `-n` to avoid clobbering the *target* file, but I want to instead refuse to clobber the *backup* file.

Is there a way to do that? I happen to be using GNU `cp` on Linux, and I'm willing to accept an answer that is specific to Linux if no POSIX option is available.

Comment: `cp` doesn't have to clobber backups.  Use ` cp --backup=t` and it will create numbered backups with no clobbering.

Comment: what is the difference between “avoid clobbering” and “refuse to clobber”?

Comment: @richard It's not a semantic difference between "avoid clobbering" and "refuse to clobber"... it's a difference of which file I'm trying not to clobber. In my case, it's the backup file, not the target file. The target file already has an option not-to-clobber. The backup file does not appear to have such an option.

Comment: @John1024 Aha. The `man` page (on Linux) doesn't explain what the 
`--backup[=CONTROL]` actually does. You have to use the `info` page, which I've always found tiresome.

Comment: Can you put that explanation into the question so it is clear, and someone can answer.

Comment: @richard I'm happy to clarify, but the middle paragraph already seems sufficient to me. I even used *italics* to stress the difference between the two types of files.

Comment: Just trying to help, it seems that, as you have no answers, that your question is unclear, or the problem is difficult.

Comment: @richard John posted the exact answer I was looking for, as a comment. If he posts it as an answer, I'll upvote + accept it.

Comment: Note that no POSIX solution _can_ be available, since there is no `-b` option.  This is specific to GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to avoid clobbering any backup files with GNU `cp`, you can use numbered backups:

```
cp --backup=t  source destination
```

Rather than overwrite a backup, this creates additional backups.

#### Example

As an example, let's consider a directory with two files:

```
$ ls
file1  file2
```

Now, let's copy file1 over file2:

```
$ cp --backup=t file1 file2
$ ls
file1  file2  file2.~1~
```

As we can see, a backup was made.

Let's copy it again:

```
$ cp --backup=t file1 file2
$ ls
file1  file2  file2.~1~  file2.~2~
```

Another backup was made.

#### Documentation

From `man cp`, just before the end of the "description" section, the various possible options for `--backup` are itemized:

> The  backup  suffix  is  '~',  unless  set  with --suffix or
>   SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.  The version control method may be selected via
>   the --backup option or through the VERSION_CONTROL environment
>   variable.  Here are the values:
>
> none, off
>             never make backups (even if --backup is given)
>
> numbered, t
>                     make numbered backups
>
> existing, nil
>                     numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
>
> simple, never
>                     always make simple backups
>
> As a special case, cp makes a backup of SOURCE when the force and
>   backup options are given and SOURCE  and  DEST  are the same name for
>   an existing, regular file.

Answer (score 0):

If you always use this to copy only one file, you can create a shell function, possibly in your `~/.bashrc` like

```
cpb () 
{ 
    if [ -r "${2}/${1}~" ] ; then 
        echo "backup of '$1' exists in '$2'"
    else 
        cp -b "$1" "$2"
    fi
}
```

and use it like this:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ cpb x dir
$ cpb x dir
$ cpb x dir
backup of 'x' exists in 'dir'
$ ls -l dir
insgesamt 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ott ott 0 Jul 16 01:09 x
-rw-r--r-- 1 ott ott 0 Jul 16 01:08 x~
```